# Custom TimerJob

Tags: custom, timer-jobs

I need to disable a custom timer job when deactivating a feature and must run the timer job on activating the feature in SharePoint 2010. Can you please help me with the code or blogs or pointers.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Within your feature receiver you can set the SPJobDefinition property isDisabled to get/set whether it is enabled.

To run the job during activation you call the RunNow method.

Here is a link to the SPJobDefinition Members - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjobdefinition_members.aspx